# Is it possible to change the Class type of an object that has a different Class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uikit

For example I have these classes:

1. MyGradientButton.h/.m
2. RedGradientButton.h/.m (Inherits the MyGradientButton class with background color red)

Now, I have an instantiated object "buttonA" that has the characteristics of MyGradientButton class. However, is it possible later on to change "buttonA" class to RedGradientButton and acquire this new class characteristics which will turn the button into red?

If possible, let me know how. Thank you

Comment: Short answer is just `NO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot change the type of a class after it's created.[1]

Best approach is typically to create a method which clones. The class variable in this case is typically the object you message.

A common example of this form is: `[NSString stringWithString:s]` against `[NSMutableString stringWithString:s];`.

Because you're dealing with a *view*, it is often easier to just define an internal type and use object composition. So you would not have a `RedGradientButton` type, but instead one `MyGradientButton` which has (for example) a `characteristics` member. Then you may create multiple characteristics types (if subclassing is really a good design).

---

[1] You *could*, but **don't** …if somebody tells you how it can be achieved. The reason: It's unsafe, and one approach is going away. Although you can set the class, which would update the methods, doing this would not modify other aspects of the object. The obvious case is that your object would not be resized or updated to reflect any difference in member layout, which means that when you message the object and it accesses members present in the subclass but not the superclass, your method's implementation would read or write to invalid memory (that's undefined behavior). Even if it appears to work or you have dynamically proven or done everything you can to ensure it is safe, modern runtimes use a non-fragile object ABI - the memory required by your base classes is free to change from one release to another. Such a design is open to other errors when resizing (leaks, memory which cannot be referenced, or memory 'initialized-at-type-conversion' to the data of another class). So even if you overcame the problem of allocation size, you would still need to devise a way to perform partial deallocation and partial initialization of your instance, in a way which leaves the object in a usable state -- quite complicated.

Answer (score 2):

The acacemic answer is: "Yes you can". 
The smarter answer is: "No you should not do that unless you understand very well what you are doing and can therefore justify yourself whether it is a good idea doing so".

If I were you then I would crate a new factory method for `RedGradientButtion` like `+(instancetype) redGradientButtonWithMyGradientButton:(MyGradientButton*)myGradientButton;`

This method could then instanciate a new `RedGradientButton` object and copy all relevant charachteristics of `myGradientButton`. Then, if you think that is a good idea, it could fetch `myGradientButtons`' superview, remove it from its superview and add the new `RedGradientButton` object instead of it. 
Of course this would make all references to `myGradientButton` to refer to an unused (but with ARC still valid) Button object. You would have to update them.

You say that `RedGradientButton` inherits from `MyGradientButton`. That means that all classes which use `MyGradientButton` should continue working well - once the references have been updated of course.